# Need help migrating hard drive using Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

So, I have a computer dual-booted with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. Despite being dual-booted, it boots straight to Windows 8 (It seems to be a recovery feature with Helwett-Packard computers, I'm using a Touchsmart 11 Notebook) and I know how to fix it, but I need help pulling it off.

I made an entire disk image backup of the 500 GB HDD to an External Drive. I made two of them since I'm going to be messing with one of them in the process to get it to work.

Note that the computer came with Windows 8, but I had to re-install it because the upgrade to Windows 10 did not go well. Windows 8 was installed before Ubuntu.

Here's what I need help doing:

1. Delete my Ubuntu install from the raw disk image and keeping Windows.
2. Shrink the partition and disk image to 250GB. (Or make a new disk image 250GB and copy everything over.)
3. Delete Windows from the actual hard drive, but keep Ubuntu so the PC boots to GRUB.
4. Increase the size of the Ubuntu install so it takes up the entire 500GB drive.
5. Setup GRUB so that it can boot from the disk image (Assuming it is on the root of the drive where Ubuntu is installed.)
6. If possible, disable certain devices in GRUB before booting. (I have a touchscreen and it seems to click randomly about 1 inch away from
   the left edge of the screen at a random Y value, I'd like to disable it due to this
   problem as I don't really need it.)

So, what should I do to pull this off?

Disk Info (lsblk command):

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3        8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0 325.5G  0 part /mnt/win
├─sda5        8:5    0 136.3G  0 part /
└─sda6        8:6    0   3.5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

(I had other drives plugged in, but I only copied and pasted the info of /dev/sda which is the only hard drive on the machine. The others were flash drives and an SD card since the external hard drive was unplugged when I ran the command.)